# Check how many times a post was called

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, request

Based on my code below, that code in my program was called multiple times I want to know how we can track if how many times def post was called and get that count and return a single response  return `Response("You received 5(the total count def post was called) questionaire.", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`. Instead of returning response everytime def post was called.Can we use a counter to detect how many times it was called ?

## code

```
 def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    questionaires_ins = QuestionaireModel.objects.get(random_code=data["random_code"])
    questionaires_ser = QuestionaireSerializer(questionaires_ins)
    questionaires_ser = questionaires_ser.data

    for applicant in data["users"]:
        user_ins = User.objects.get(id=applicant["basic_info"]["user_id"])
        user_ser = UserSerializer(user_ins)
 .......
        email_ins = Email()
        email_ins.share_questionaire_link(data_to_send)

    return Response("You received a questionaire.", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Use a global variable and increment it inside def?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
count = 0
def myFunction(args):
    #Code
    global count
    count += 1
    return f'This function was called {count} times'
```

**Edit:** This is how you'd implement it in your code:

```
count = 0
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    questionaires_ins = QuestionaireModel.objects.get(random_code=data["random_code"])
    questionaires_ser = QuestionaireSerializer(questionaires_ins)
    questionaires_ser = questionaires_ser.data

    for applicant in data["users"]:
        user_ins = User.objects.get(id=applicant["basic_info"]["user_id"])
        user_ser = UserSerializer(user_ins)


        .......
        email_ins = Email()
        email_ins.share_questionaire_link(data_to_send)

        global count
        count += 1

        return Response(f"You received {count} questionaire.", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: How is this logic being connected to the post function Sir ? how a counter been connected to def post?

Comment: Check out the **Edit**

Comment: How do you mean it?

Comment: cause want i want bro is i only want to return this  return Response("You received questionaire." , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)  once . So for example if def post was called 2 times then count = 2 then i will return this   return Response("You received questionaire." , status=status.HTTP_200_OK) .Cause in my program right now everytime def post was called then it also returns   return Response("You received questionaire." , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't really determine what you want by that

Comment: lets talk in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189716/discussion-between-jhon-caylog-and-aeossa).

Comment: lets talk in chat

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want define global variable like what is @Aeossa said you can define a decorator like this:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    helper.calls = 0
    helper.__name__= func.__name__
    return helper
```

and use it outside of your function like this:

```
@call_counter
def post(self, request):
            data = request.data
            print(data)
            questionaires_ins = QuestionaireModel.objects.get(random_code=data["random_code"])
            questionaires_ser = QuestionaireSerializer(questionaires_ins)
            questionaires_ser = questionaires_ser.data

            for applicant in data["users"]:
                user_ins = User.objects.get(id=applicant["basic_info"]["user_id"])
                user_ser = UserSerializer(user_ins)
         .......
                email_ins = Email()
                email_ins.share_questionaire_link(data_to_send)

            return Response("You received a questionaire.", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

after that every time you call the `post` function you can access to the number of calls through `calls`. for example:

```
post(SomeRequest)
post(AnotherRequest)
print (post.calls)

# returns 2
```

for more information please read this link : https://www.python-course.eu/python3_count_function_calls.php